# selectize does not work in meteor

Tags: meteor

Can any one tell me why this work in meteor:

```
"landTenancyType" : {
  type: String, 
  optional: true,
  autoform: {
    type: "selectize",
    options: function(){

     return [
      {label: "Joint", value: "Joint"},
      {label: "Tenancy In Common", value: "Tenancy In Common"}
     ]
  }
 }
}
```

but this does not work:

```
"landTenancyType" : {
  type: String, 
  optional: true,
  autoform: {
    type: "selectize",
    options: function(){
       return Categories.find().map(function(obj) {
         console.log(obj);
         return { label: obj.name, value: obj.name };
      });

  }
}
}
```

All the necessary publish and subscribe are working. Console does also show that values are coming from the collection. However a blank selectize ui is killing me. If i change  type: "selectize", to type: "select", the select list is populated but i do not have the selectize goodness i need. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

By the way I am using meteor with autoform 5.0 and comerc:autoform-selectize.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
Categories.find().map(function(obj)
```

`find` returns a cursor, you could do `find().fetch()` to get an array. Then `map` would work on that array.

Comment: I have moved on to https://github.com/vazco/meteor-universe-autoform-select but that answer does make sense.

Comment: fetch() still didn't work for me. The array is empty at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you return object wittin another objects from a function ? A function will always return a single entity (either single value or single object). Please re-check your code's following section:

```
options: function(){
   return Categories.find().map(function(obj) {
     console.log(obj);
     return { label: obj.name, value: obj.name };
   });
}
```

Comment: This is a standard example i see all over this and other forums using meteor. Remember the code works if the type: 'select' is used but not if type:'selectize' .